# Would it be possible to have "method/field" literals comparable to the class literals in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, class, scala, reflection, language-design

Java's `Foo.class` as well Scala's `classOf[Foo]` literal class syntax return a reflective view about the class in question.

Is it possible and would it make sense to provide something like `.method/.field` or `methodOf[]`/`fieldOf[]` for getting comparable reflective access to methods and fields?

How would something like this be implemented in Java/Scala?

In the case of Java, I would assume that this would either require a language change (very unlikely) or some wizardry with bytecode tools/AspectJ, whereas in Scala it is probably possible to implement it with an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.  Paul Phillips has certainly expressed an interest in such a thing, and there's a lot of work currently happening in trunk around the forthcoming scala reflections.

It's doubtful that we'll see anything like your proposed syntax though.  Methods are not a first-class construct and, as such, and only be referenced via their containing class.  But we *will* be getting a nice scala-friendly way to access members via reflection, including default params, parameter names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall where, but I stumbled across a Java library recently that would take Java classes as input and generate a metaclass, so to speak, that had static fields (I think) that were references to all of the fields and methods on the target class. It's certainly not as elegant as what you're looking for, but it struck me as a potentially useful bit of wizardry.